# Remoting Event Handling: Specifying an available range of listening ports

Tags: .net, remoting, port

I have a client-server application that uses .NET remoting.

The server sends update event to the client via .NET events. (That was a big deal to get working, but it has been deployed for seven months without problems.)

To be able to listen to events, the client has to create a listening channel. My app.config file specifies port "0", meaning "any available port".

All good, but now the customer's network administrators are trying to tighten up the firewalls. They asked if we can use a fixed port. I replied that this would be possible, but then you wouldn't be able to have multiple clients running on the same machine. You also couldn't have multiple users using the application from the same Citrix server. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Now they are asking if I can specify a range of ports that the client application can pick from.

Does anyone know of a straightforward way to do this: make it so that the client creates a listening channel on the first available port within a range?